# How to bind an object from one window to another control in another window in wpf? (c#)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I would like to bind an object that already exist in one window to texts box in another windows.
I have this object (car) that already bind to this window-

```
public partial class Car_UI : Window
{
    BE.Car car = new BE.Car();//this is the object
public Car_UI()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = car;
    }
}
```

one of the fields of car is a struct I would like to bind to a new windw- I tried this but it isn't working

```
 private void slc_ch_cartype(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBoxItem lbi = ((sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem);
        if ("other" == lbi.Content.ToString())
        {
            new carType_UI(){ DataContext =car.typecar/*this is the field in car I'm tring to bind*/}.Show();

        }
    }
```

this is cartype

```
 public struct CarType
{
    public string Manufacturer;
    public  string Model;
    public  int Volume;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string s = String.Format(
          @"Manufacturer: {0} Model: {1} Volume: {2}"
           , Manufacturer, Model, Volume);
        return s;
    }
}
```

and this is the binding in the xaml-

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtbx_manf" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
        <TextBox.Text>
            <Binding Path="Manufacturer" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                <Binding.ValidationRules>
                    <local:StringRangeValidationRule MinimumLength="1" MaximumLength="50" ErrorMessage="Manufacturer is required to be at least 1 charecthers." />
                </Binding.ValidationRules>
            </Binding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

for some reason this doesn't work, does any one know why?

thanks, for the answer.
fields cannot be binding, only properties.

Comment: Data bindig works with public properties only, not with fields. Change Manufacturer to `public string Manufacturer { get; set; }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I can see that Manufacturer is defined in a **Struct** CarType.
The reason its not working is

- Struct is a value type and binding will obtain a copy of it hence never update original object.

I suggest you change CarType to **class**

Comment: thanks, I did change it to property and it was working, but when Ichanged it to class it's stoped working, do you know why?

Comment: @ehoodporat It's not working because you haven't implemented INotifyPropertyChanged  like I told you. When in doubt [check the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

The property in your `CarType` struct is actually a field, not a property, so the WPF binding will not bind to it.

You need to:

- ensure the DataContext of the TextBox is a `CarType` object
- and you use proper properties, not fields - preferably also implementing INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: thank you.
what will the INotifyPropertyChanged help me?

Comment: first thanks for the help.
second,  even after I implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged,
it's still doesn't bind the object.
 I also implemented  INotifyPropertyChanged for the Car class, which CarType object is a filed inside
(and obviously I used property due to the mistake I did before.)